# how to fix window in background?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, winapi

I want to make that window doesn't become foreground while execute postmessage().
But, while execute program, window become foreground.

```
point = (x,y);
lParam = makePararm(x,y);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, lParam);
sleep(0.03);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, lParam);
```

This program is that click x,y.
I want to click window in background (not become foreground!)
Could someone please help?

Comment: You are sending a mouse message to the window, as if the user is clicking the mouse. The receiving application cannot differentiate between this, it just thinks you clicked it with the mouse and so it decides to get activated. When the application you send the message to is yours (and you have the source of it), you can let it handle a custom message and send that message instead. Now you are just simulating a mouse click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a mouse message to the window, as if the user is clicking the mouse. The receiving application cannot differentiate between this, it just thinks you clicked it with the mouse and so it decides to get activated.

When the application you send the message to is yours (and you have the source of it), you can let it handle a custom message and send that message instead.

Now you are just simulating a mouse click.

Comment: Thank you R.Beiboer. I understand. Then, if handle a custom message, what can i use to make custom message?

Comment: @Reavil use one of the message numbers in the [`WM_APP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644930%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) range.

Comment: You need to define a new message in the range WM_APP to 0xBFFF. Just handle this message in the WndProc of the window you send this message to.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, R. Beiboer Thank, you. your advise is very helpful.